# Unable to access web app on Heroku server using docker

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to host my web app on Heroku using docker

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest as base
RUN apk add --no-cache --update python3 py3-pip bash
ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -q -r /tmp/requirements.txt
ADD ./ /webapp/
WORKDIR /webapp
CMD uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT} --log-level trace --use-colors
```

I checked the web app works on my mac (localhost) using docker-compose (by setting PORT=8000)

But on Heroku server, the deploy was done but I couldn't access the app.
The following is error I got when I access the link Heroku generate.
The response should be 200 code, and return "Hello world"

```
2021-09-18T05:49:29.841550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=(my-app-name) request_id=d514423e-de8c-4f65-8277-25d1123e7a6e fwd="150.249.159.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-18T05:49:30.097458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=(my-app-name) request_id=ae880636-68bf-4f20-9ee1-e78abcecac81 fwd="150.249.159.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Does anyone knows how I access my app ?
I guess it is because of the PORT environment

Best regards.

Comment: Could you please try using another base image? such as `debian` or `ubuntu`. I faced the same issue long ago with k8

Answer (score 1):

Do not use curly brackets around `$PORT`

```
--port $PORT
```

Comment: It works !! Thank you very much. But I had to add directory "CMD uvicorn webapp.main:app" even though I write "WORKDIR /webapp". Do you know why ??